# Python's Tkinter Horizontal Scroll with Buttons not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to iterate image buttons horizontally. Scrollbar appears fine but it is not showing up more items when scroll. This scrollbar works perfectly fine on vertical scroll. Please review below code:

```
`from tkinter_scroll import *
from tkinter import *

for index in range(i):
    if len(PHOTOS[index]) > 0:
        for k,photo in enumerate(PHOTOS[index]):
            img_text = ""
            btn= Button(scrollable_body, highlightbackground='red', fg='red', text=img_text,bg='white',border='0', image=photo, command = lambda index=index, k=k: put_sprite(index,k), compound=LEFT, width='100', height='110')
            btn.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand="no", padx="5", pady="5")
            BTNS.append(btn)
scrollable_body.update()

#===== Tkinter Class ====
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Scrollable(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, frame, width=16):
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width, orient='horizontal')
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
        
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=800, height=120, bg='white',xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.__fill_canvas)
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, frame)
        self.windows_item = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self, anchor=tk.W)
    def __fill_canvas(self, event):
        "Enlarge the windows item to the canvas width"
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.windows_item, width=canvas_width)
    def update(self):
        "Update the canvas and the scrollregion"
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.windows_item))
```

Comment: Why do you set the internal frame (instance of `Scrollable`) to the width of canvas if you want horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Also `Scrollable` inherits from `ttk.Frame`, but you call `tk.Frame.__init__(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your class `Scrollable`:

- `Scrollable` inherits from `ttk.Frame`, but you called `tk.Frame.__init__(...)`
- if you want to scroll horizontally, why do you set the width of the internal frame (i.e. instance of `Scrollable`) to same as the canvas?
- it is better to bind `<Configure>` event of the internal frame and update `scrollregion` of the canvas inside the bind callback

Below is the updated class `Scrollable` and an example of using it:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Scrollable(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, frame, width=16):
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width, orient='horizontal')
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=800, height=120, bg='white', xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.windows_item = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.windows_item)))

root = tk.Tk()

scrollable = Scrollable(root)

for i in range(20):
    tk.Button(scrollable, text=i+1, width=20).pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]